# Module parse failed Unexpected character � need an appropriate loader to handle this file type currently no loaders are configured to process the file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, electron

I am trying to use 'node-crc' in my react electron app, I am trying to make build of the app and getting this error.

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-crc/index.node 1:2
[0] Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
[0] You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

I am not sure if this issue is related to **Rust Setup** required in system to use this libaray